# ADODB decimal in VB6 / VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, decimal, adodb

I have a data access component using ADODB (MDAC 2.8) that uses an ADODB.recordset to read a sql server table containing a column defined as decimal(15,2).

This data access component is written in VB6 and is used in our software for years now.

Now we must write a compatible component without VB6 (so we did a rewrite in VB.NET).

For easier shift to the new component we sticked to use ADODB from VB.NET.

Now the question: 
If I read a value from the column that contains the data of "50000" (no decimals) and return it as a string, the vb6 component delivers "50000", where the VBNET version delivers "50000,00".

So this may be a cosmetic issue only as internal representaion is ok but I wonder if there is a switch to determine how the decimals are returned.

In addition: any links refering this compatibility issues in this range are welcome...

Regards
Klaus

Comment: Isn't this a VB.Net question rather than a VB6 question? I'm adding VB.Net to the tags

Comment: You can explicitly control the string formatting in VB.Net if you use the ToString method. Have a look at the overloads. You can pass a format string to control how many decimal places are shown if any, and you can pass CultureInfo objects which allow you to choose whether you want the decimal separator to be a dot or a comma

Comment: Please tell me you reading decimal into a decimal and not a string.

Comment: Tony, for computation we fill decimal vars, but my question goes to presentation. Take into account that we have tons of sources that rely on this

Comment: MarkJ I am aware of having this formating options - but we have a really large code base that uses the component as is - no chance to look at every reference...

Answer (score 1):

I see two big mistakes here:

> For easier shift to the new component we sticked to use ADODB from VB.NET.

There's no good reason for this. You'll thank yourself sooner (not later) for using the ADO.Net API rather than the older ADODB.

> If I read a value from the column that contains the data of "50000" (no decimals) and return it as a string

Ugh. Keep numeric data as numeric data. Use the Decimal type throughout your code, right up to last possible moment before you actually display the data to the user.

Comment: Joel, in an ideal world I would agree, but regarding budget and people its far away from that. So the question stays: is there a way to let ADODB work the same way no matter from where I call it?